# Scale Google Column Chart to fit div element

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I have a problem when I want to show a Google Column Chart in a div element. It shows correctly, but not the whole chart. In the bottom image, you can see what I mean: every chart should have 1000 or 2000 elements in the horizontal axes, but only about 350 are shown.

If I increase the div element size, then the chart grows bigger and more elements are presented, but I don't want that, I want to whole chart to fit in the div element.

[image: Histograms not showing whole scale]

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

edit:

This is piece of code:

```html
 histograms = [
 ['0', 0.0, '7FCC28'],
 ['1', 0.0, '7FCC28'], 
 ['2', 0.0, '7FCC28'],
 ['3', 0.0, '7FCC28'], 
 ['4', 0.0, '7FCC28'],
 ['5', 0.0, '7FCC28']....] //one array can have up to 4000 elements

    {% for hist in histograms %}
        i = i+1;
        
        var feat_name = 'feature_name' + i;
         
        var h = {{ hist|safe }};
        h.unshift(["Position", "Value", { role: "style" } ]);
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(h);
        
       var options = {
         title: "Histogram",
   width: 2.5*h.length,
   fontSize: 12,
         bar: {groupWidth: "100%"},
         chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"80%"},
         legend: { position: "none" },
   hAxis: {showTextEvery: 50,
   viewWindow: {max:h.length,
       min:0}
     },

       };
  
  div_name = 'histogram_div' + i;
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(div_name));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        {% endfor %}
```

My whole code is complex, but I'm sure this is enough for giving some clue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us your code? or, even better, create a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: tried `hAxis.viewWindow.min` and / or `hAxis.viewWindow.max` from the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options)?

Comment: Those are my options- tried hAxis.viewWindow.min and hAxis.viewWindow.max but without success. I'm pretty sure it is one of the options and I tried a lot of them, but no luck for me...

       var options = {
         title: "Histogram",

   width: 2.5*h.length,

   fontSize: 12,

         bar: {groupWidth: "100%"},

         chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"80%"},


         legend: { position: "none" },

   hAxis: {showTextEvery: 50,

   viewWindow: {max:h.length}
},

       };

Comment: it would really help to see the code and a sample of the data. are you using a Continuous or Discrete axis?

Comment: I edited opening post, I insert relevent piece of code...